# Multiple tests in one pytest function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a "conceptual" question regarding pytest and how I should handle multiple tests.

Let's say I need to test something for a bunch of strings: `names = [" ", "a ", " a", " a "]`.

I could create multiple `test_` functions to test them individually, but they would be exactly the same, but with different input.

I was thinking on doing something like:

```
def test_names():
    names = [" ", "a ", " a", " a "]
    for name in names:
        with pytest.raises(errors.MyFooError) as ex:
            random_method(name)
```

The problem is: doing this, in case one element doesn't raise `errors.MyFooError`, I would receive this:

```
Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'errors.MyFooError'
```

The message is generic, I have no idea in which element this occurred.

I would probably just split into 4 tests, one for each element of the list, I guess this is the correct way to do it? What happens if the list is huge?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use the `parametrize` capabilities of `pytest` as shown [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html).

Your code would look as

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('input', [" ", "a ", " a", " a "])
def test_names(input):
    with pytest.raises(errors.MyFooError) as ex:
        random_method(input)
```